# python IOError exception

Tags: python

I am getting the following exception in my python script.The script is running 24*7 and it throws the below exception every two hours.Any thoughts on when this exception happen will be useful.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "ApprovedLeadTracker.py", line 337, in ?
    processSendMailTo(sendMailTo,dedup_leads,icenet_leads,dedup_leads_tot)
    File "ApprovedLeadTracker.py", line 274, in processSendMailTo
    ue_db.processQuery(q=query)
    File "/public/gdp/trunk/src/ukl/python/database.py", line 63, in processQuery
    print traceback.format_exc()
    IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

database.py

```
def processQuery(self, q, locals=None, returnLastRowId = False, opt=''):
        ret = None
        err = ''
        for i in range(2):
            try:
                cursor = self.getCursor(opt)
                cursor.execute(q,locals)
                if (returnLastRowId):
                    ret = cursor.lastrowid
                else:
                    ret = cursor.fetchall()
                cursor.close()
                #q = cursor._last_executed
                #self.log('SUCCESS',q)
                return ret
            except MySQLdb.OperationalError, e:
                print "Exception Query:", q
                print "Exception:", e
                err = e
                print traceback.format_exc()
                self.conn = self.connect()
            except Exception, e:
                print "Exception Query:", q
                print "Exception:", e
                err = e
                print traceback.format_exc()
                self.conn = self.connect()
                break
        #q = cursor._last_executed
        #self.log('FAILURE',q)
        raise RuntimeError, str(err)
```

Comment: @Lattywhere MySQLdb.OperationalError is occuring

Comment: @Scorpil MySQLdb.OperationalError is occuring

Comment: @shiva how do you run the script?

Comment: @wRAR the script will run for the set of data over certain period of time and went to sleep for 15 min and again run for the set of data

Comment: @shiva how do you invoke the script?

Comment: Error 5 often implies a hardware fault - check the system error log files like /var/log/messsages (depending on syslogd settings)

Comment: Where does `traceback` even come from?